# AngularJS + Jersey POST Bad Request

Tags: angularjs, jersey

I have following API in jersey for file upload :

```
@Path("/image/upload")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response Imageupload(
            @QueryParam("filename") String filename,
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputString, 
            @Context ContainerRequestContext crc)
            throws ConnectException, SQLException, InvalidCredentialsException, IOException, GeneralException {
}
```

and I am using angular js for uploading file :

```
_myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {

        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('file', file);




        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.token
                },
                 params:{
                         'filename':file.name
                }
            })
            .success(function() {

            })
            .error(function() {

            });
    }
}]);



_myApp.controller('uploadImageController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'fileUpload', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, fileUpload) {

                $rootScope.show = true;

                $scope.upload = function() {
               //$scope.fileObject is the File I am trying to upload
                        console.log($scope.fileObject);
                        var file = $scope.fileObject;



                        var uploadUrl = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/ImageAPIS/image/upload";

                        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);

                }
```

I am getting the following error :

**400 Bad request : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**
Am I posting the request in wrong Angular standard? I can see the payload being sent, What mismatch is between the Jersey and my Angular request sent?
I have refereed the following File upload code -
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

Comment: Since you are append the filename to the multipart body (`fd.append('filename', file.name);`), you should also be getting the name a multipart part, not a query param. i.e. `@FormDataParam("filename") String filename`. I don't know if this is the reason for the error though.

Comment: I have Modified the Form Data, I removed the filename which  I was  appending, and sending it as params now. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}`. I think by setting the content-type explicitly, you lose the browser setting the boundary, which _would_ cause a bad request

Comment: Why is it wrong to set Content-Type: multipart/form-data ? does setting Content-Type: undefined mean it'll adjust the Content-Type automatically?

Comment: Yes, the browser will set it, along with the boundary which is appended to the Content-Type. If you don't know what a boundary is, do some searching on multipart. But the boundary is required. If it's not there, that would cause a bad request response from the server